# Makefile Helper Function Not Expanding As Expected When Called

Tags: bash, makefile

## Problem Statement

I have a makefile that I'm attempting to make a helper function for. I want to be able to call the defined helper function but when I'm looking at the text expansion for the targets they're coming out as an empty string.

I'm looking to figure out where I'm messing up my Makefile syntax to cause the empty expansion.

## Makefile

```
# Helper function to instantiate templates.
define render_template
$(eval $@_HOST_URI = "git@github.com:company-name")
$(eval $@_TEMPLATE_NAME = $(1))
$(eval $@_TEMPLATE_DIR = $(1)s)
$(eval $@_NAME = $(2))
cd ${$@_TEMPLATE_DIR}; cookiecutter --no-input git@github.com:company-name/terraform-${$@_TEMPLATE_NAME}.git ${$@_TEMPLATE_NAME}_name=${$@_NAME};
endef

# TODO: Add steps to build a Python3 venv and use it to build the local template.
.PHONY: new-service
new-service: ## Accesses Docker Shell (advanced)
        if [ -z "$(SERVICE_NAME)" ]; then \
            echo "SERVICE_NAME is a required parameter. Example usage 'make new SERVICE_NAME=vpc-networking'"; \
        else \
            $(call render_template,"service",${SERVICE_NAME}) \
        fi
```

## Error Output

```
% make new-service SERVICE_NAME=example
if [ -z "example" ]; then \
            echo "SERVICE_NAME is a required parameter. Example usage 'make new SERVICE_NAME=vpc-networking'"; \
        else \
             \
        fi
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: `if [ -z "example" ]; then     echo "SERVICE_NAME is a required parameter. Example usage 'make new SERVICE_NAME=vpc-networking'"; else      fi'
make: *** [new-service] Error 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO it's a very bad idea to do things like this.  But I will explain what's happening so you understand it.

When a `define` is created, all the newlines are preserved inside the variable; that's what makes a `define` different from a normal variable assignment where backslash-newlines are removed.

When a variable is expanded in a recipe context, all the newlines are preserved just as if you'd typed them by hand. That's what allows you to put a complete recipe with multiple commands inside a `define` variable then use it in a recipe and it expands to multiple commands.

In your situation, the `eval` functions expand to the empty string after assigning the variables, so the expanded value of the `call` function will be something like:

```
define render_template




cd "service"s; cookiecutter --no-input git@github.com:company-name/terraform-"service".git "service"_name=;
endef
```

The newlines here put the `cd` on its own line, not inside the same if-statement.  So make will run it AFTER the if-statement, but since the if-statement fails it never gets the chance.

If you add backslashes to ensure the entire `define` is on line line, like this:

```
define render_template
$(eval $@_HOST_URI = "git@github.com:company-name") \
$(eval $@_TEMPLATE_NAME = $(1)) \
$(eval $@_TEMPLATE_DIR = $(1)s) \
$(eval $@_NAME = $(2)) \
cd ${$@_TEMPLATE_DIR}; cookiecutter --no-input git@github.com:company-name/terraform-${$@_TEMPLATE_NAME}.git ${$@_TEMPLATE_NAME}_name=${$@_NAME};
endef
```

then it will work.  Or you could use simple variable assignment:

```
render_template = \
    $(eval $@_HOST_URI = "git@github.com:company-name") \
    $(eval $@_TEMPLATE_NAME = $(1)) \
    $(eval $@_TEMPLATE_DIR = $(1)s) \
    $(eval $@_NAME = $(2)) \
    cd ${$@_TEMPLATE_DIR}; cookiecutter --no-input git@github.com:company-name/terraform-${$@_TEMPLATE_NAME}.git ${$@_TEMPLATE_NAME}_name=${$@_NAME};
```

Comment: This answers my question and I thank you for that. I'm also curious what you think would be a better idea to reduce code duplication. Particularly when I have two make targets that do the same thing but have slight changes in their arguments.

Comment: In general using `eval`, which sets **GLOBAL** variables, inside a `define` which is used in a local context in a recipe, is IMO not great.  In general in my opinion `eval` should be used only in the most extreme situations as it makes your makefile hard to trace and reason about.  For this specific example, I would just use the `$1` values etc. directory, I wouldn't try to set global variables using `eval`.  Alternatively you can make global variables like `HOST_URI=...`, `TEMPLATE_NAME = $1` etc. as global variables, no need to prefix them with `$@` etc.